# Unable to track connected users using Signalr hub class

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have created a class that inherits the Signalr Hub class and it runs on startup. When a connection is made, there are some custom headers sent from the client that I use to generate a user object. I want to store these in memory on the server so that I can retrieve the list and display them in a UI. Someone can then use this UI to see the user info and perform interactions with this connection. I have setup a hub class in an ASP MVC project and i am using a console app for the client. I can connect fine and the server can communicate back, but the property that I use in the hub class to keep track of the connected users is reset to null every time a request is made to the hub class.

```
public class JobRunHandler : Hub
{
    private List<JobRunClient> RunningJobs { get; set; }

    public JobRunHandler()
    {
        if(this.RunningJobs == null) this.RunningJobs = new List<JobRunClient>();
}

public override Task OnConnected()
{
    JobRunClient runclient = new JobRunClient()
    {
        ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId,
        Someotherstuff = this.GetHeaderInt(Context.Headers["Someotherstuff"])
    };

    this.RunningJobs.Add(runclient);
    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    var existingClient = this.GetConnectingClient();
    if (existingClient == null)
    {
        JobRunClient runclient = new JobRunClient()
        {
            ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId,
            Someotherstuff = this.GetHeaderInt(Context.Headers["Someotherstuff"])
        };

        this.RunningJobs.Add(runclient);
    }
    return base.OnReconnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    this.RemoveClient(Context.ConnectionId);
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}

public void TestMethod()
{
    Clients.All.ping();
    var client = this.GetConnectingClient();
}
```

}

I have put break points in every method so i know when it runs. The client never disconnects or triggers reconnect, so there is no issue with the connection being broken. The client connects and the `OnConnected()` method triggers and the value is added to `this.RunningJobs`. The client then calls the `TestMethod()` which works, but when i check `this.RunningJobs` it is empty.

When `Clients.All.ping();` runs it does actually send a ping back to the client. So the connection is made successfully, the server maintains the connection and i can send a ping back to the client when a separate method is called, but for some reason the property is being reset and I dont know why. I can use redis for this if I have to, but I have seen others use this strategy and its not been an issue.

Here is the client code I have created to test this (the console app)

```
    var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:2497/");
    hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    IHubProxy myHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("JobRunHandler");

    myHubProxy.On("ping", () => Console.Write("Recieved ping \n"));
    hubConnection.Headers.Add("Someotherstuff", "1");
    hubConnection.Start().Wait();


    while(true)
    {
        myHubProxy.Invoke("BroadcastCompletion").ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("!!! There was an error opening the connection:{0} \n", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
            }

        }).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Broadcast sent to the server.\n");
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The hub is transient. SignalR creates a hub instance each time a hub method is invoked so you cannot store any state in an instance property between the calls.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the property being used for this to a ConcurrentDictionary and this seems to be doing the trick. It allows me to store the client connections across all connections. I used the following code for this.

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, JobRunClient> RunningJobs = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, JobRunClient>();
```